# Join lines at pattern. Uneven interval

Tags: awk, sed

If I have this...

```
6,
9,
12
"url": "https://www.url.com"
6,
9,
12
"url": "https://www.url.com"
13,
16
"url": "https://www.url.com"
"url": "https://www.url.com"
18
"url": "https://www.url.com"
"url": "https://www.url.com"
3,
6,
14
"url": "https://www.url.com"
"url": "https://www.url.com"
20
"url": "https://www.url.com"
74
"url": "https://www.url.com"
```

How can I join the lines in a way that gives me this...

```
6,9,12"url": "https://www.url.com"
6,9,12"url": "https://www.url.com"
13,16"url": "https://www.url.com"
"url": "https://www.url.com"
18"url": "https://www.url.com"
"url": "https://www.url.com"
3,6,14"url": "https://www.url.com"
"url": "https://www.url.com"
20"url": "https://www.url.com"
74"url": "https://www.url.com"
```

I have tried using sed to delete the newline on lines that start with a number, but it doesn't work. I think because the lines are changing as its working?

```
sed '/^[0-9]/N;s/\n//'
```

I get this...

```
6,9,
12"url": "https://www.url.com"
6,9,
12"url": "https://www.url.com"
13,16
"url": "https://www.url.com"
"url": "https://www.url.com"
18"url": "https://www.url.com"
"url": "https://www.url.com"
3,6,
14"url": "https://www.url.com"
"url": "https://www.url.com"
20"url": "https://www.url.com"
74"url": "https://www.url.com"
```

EDIT:
Thanks for the help and explanations.
I went with this one because it was easier for me to understand. They all worked though. `sed ':a;/https/!{N;ba};s/\n//g'`

Comment: `I think because the lines are changing as its working?` - no, you just work with two lines. You script is: { If the line starts with `[0-9]`, append next line to pattern space. Remove newline. Then print. }.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code should work:

```
sed ':a;/https/!{N;ba};s/\n//g'
```

It is essentially a while loop, which appends line after line, as long as the outcoming multiline does ***not*** contain `https`; as soon as one line is appended which contains `https`, the while loop is abandoned (as the `b` command is not executed), and all embedded newlines `\n` are removed with the `s` command.

More in detail, the script (between single quotes) can be rewritten like this:

```
:a        # label you can jump to with a t or b command
/https/!{ # if the line does not match "https" do what's in {…}:
    N     #   append the next line to the current one (putting "\n" in between)
    ba    #   branch to the line labelled as ":a"
}
s/\n//g   # change all newlines to empty strings (i.e. remove all newlines for the current multi-line)
```

The corresponding pseudo-code would be

```
begin
while line does not contain "https" {
  append another line
}
remove all newlines
```

Answer (score 5):

One way using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
awk '{ printf("%s%s", $0, /^[0-9]/ ? "" : "\n") }' file.txt
```

Comment: This is a generically good method of parsing stuff like this, comma delimited files that contain line breaks, and the like

Comment: If a trailing newline is required to help handle the (odd?) case where the last line starts with the match pattern, append `END { printf("%s", /^[0-9]/ ? "\n" : "")` to the awk command

Comment: Use `ORS` instead of hard-coding the value that you hope ORS will be, `"\n"`, i.e. `printf "%s%s", $0, (/^[0-9]/ ? "" : ORS)`

Answer (score 3):

```
sed '/^[0-9]/{H;d};H;s/.*//;x;s/\n//g'
```

- `/^[0-9]/` - If the line starts with a digit.

  - `H` - Append the line to hold space.
  - `d` - Delete the line and start over.
- If the line does not start with a digit
- `H` - Append the line to hold space to all the digits there.
- `s/.*//` - Clear pattern space. I want to clear hold space.
- `x` - Switch pattern space with hold space.
- `s/\n//g` - Replace all the newlines by nothing.
- And here the line with the numbers are printed.

Answer (score 0):

If your pattern is in file+.txt:-

Save this as script+.sh, or whatever you want to call it.

```
#!/bin/sh -x

init () {
rm -v ./report+.txt

cat > edchop+.txt << EOF
1,${line}w temp
1,${line}d
wq
EOF

next
}

end () {
rm -v ./edchop+.txt
rm -v ./temp
exit 0
}

next () {
[[ -s file+.txt ]] && main
end
}

main () {
line=$(echo "/url/n" | ed -s file+.txt | cut -b1)
ed -s file+.txt < edchop+.txt
sed -i s'/com\"/com\"-/g' temp
cat temp | tr -d '\n' | tr '-' '\n' >> report+.txt
next
}

init
```

In hindsight, this is a bit hacky.  I've used the .com suffix in the web address as a newline anchor with sed and tr; you will need to change that to whatever domain you are using.